# Deleting one of the OSs in a multiboot arrangement

Tags: grub2

I am multibooting Windows 7, Linux Mint and Suse Leap on one computer, having installed these OSs in that order and each into separate partitions. 
Since Suse was the last OS to be installed, the Grub2 boot loader configured under Suse is the one producing the boot menu and controlling the  boot sequence.
I now wish to delete the Suse partition and multiboot just Win 7 and Mint. Logically, I must delete the Suse partition and revert to the grub2 boot loader created when I installed Mint, but just how to do this?

Comment: Should be as simple as editing the list of OS that grub relies on, what does your research indcate, is required to do that?

Comment: My research has not been  very effective because I have not had a clear picture of just what is going on and where, when the OS install program, using Grub2, writes the Grub boot loader.